# How can I split a batch string message received from Azure Service Bus to row by row?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm a beginner in python, I have an Azure function that runs with a time trigger. This function reads a batch of raw JSON data from an Azure service bus with string format.

This is a two-row of data. In reality, I received about 50 like this message is continuous. Now I want to split this message row by row and then archive it to Azure Storage.

The message is like the below sample ( concat of row1 and row2 ) :

```
{"Name":"","Seri":21000000,"SiName":"","As":"","PId":21070101,"ICheck":0,"SeeNum":405097041391424,"Type":0,"Counter":33,"PaId":0,"MeType":30,"RecTime":"2021-10-21T09:04:41.0151Z","ReaTime":null,"Cape":"2021-10-21T09:04:40.644","Status":0,"text":"{\"TYPE_TAG\":\"00\",\"ENSORAG\":{\"date_time\":\"2021-10-21 09:04:40.644\",\"seber\":10,\"seqmber\":405097041391424,\"lo_name\":\"\",\"accati\":{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":-0.037665367,\"2\":-0.033863068,\"3\":-0.026795387,\"4\":-0.03757,\"5\":-0.02809906,\"6\":-0.016090393,\"7\":-0.040496826,\"8\":-0.05318451,\"9\":-0.025012016,\"10\":-0.057872772}},\"ATTACHED_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER_TAG\":\"21000000\",\"error\":{}}","CerId":null,"Id":null,"Asse":null,"Id":0,"id":"075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d","t":-1}{"Name":"","Seri":21000000,"SiName":"","As":"","PId":21070101,"ICheck":0,"SeeNum":405097041391424,"Type":0,"Counter":33,"PaId":0,"MeType":30,"RecTime":"2021-10-21T09:04:41.0151Z","ReaTime":null,"Cape":"2021-10-21T09:04:40.644","Status":0,"text":"{\"TYPE_TAG\":\"00\",\"ENSORAG\":{\"date_time\":\"2021-10-21 09:04:40.644\",\"seber\":10,\"seqmber\":405097041391424,\"lo_name\":\"\",\"accati\":{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":-0.037665367,\"2\":-0.033863068,\"3\":-0.026795387,\"4\":-0.03757,\"5\":-0.02809906,\"6\":-0.016090393,\"7\":-0.040496826,\"8\":-0.05318451,\"9\":-0.025012016,\"10\":-0.057872772}},\"NUMBER_TAG\":\"21000000\",\"error\":{}}","CerId":null,"Id":null,"Asse":null,"Id":0,"id":"075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d","t":-1}{"Name":"","Seri":4560000,"SiName":"","As":"","PId":2107401,"ICheck":0,"SeeNum":40509704561424,"Type":0,"Counter":34,"PaId":0,"MeType":31,"RecTime":"2021-10-21T09:04:41.0151Z","ReaTime":null,"Cape":"2021-10-21T09:04:40.644","Status":0,"text":"{\"TYPE_TAG\":\"00\",\"ENSORAG\":{\"date_time\":\"2021-10-21 09:04:40.644\",\"seber\":10,\"seqmber\":405097041391424,\"lo_name\":\"\",\"accati\":{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":-0.037665367,\"2\":-0.033863068,\"3\":-0.026795387,\"4\":-0.03757,\"5\":-0.02809906,\"6\":-0.016090393,\"7\":-0.040496826,\"8\":-0.05318451,\"9\":-0.025012016,\"10\":-0.057872772}},\"ATTACHED_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER_TAG\":\"21000000\",\"error\":{}}","CerId":null,"Id":null,"Asse":null,"Id":0,"id":"075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d","t":-1}{"Name":"","Seri":21000000,"SiName":"","As":"","PId":21070101,"ICheck":0,"SeeNum":405097041391424,"Type":0,"Counter":33,"PaId":0,"MeType":30,"RecTime":"2021-10-21T09:04:41.0151Z","ReaTime":null,"Cape":"2021-10-21T09:04:40.644","Status":0,"text":"{\"TYPE_TAG\":\"00\",\"ENSORAG\":{\"date_time\":\"2021-10-21 09:04:40.644\",\"seber\":10,\"seqmber\":405097041391424,\"lo_name\":\"\",\"accati\":{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":-0.037665367,\"2\":-0.033863068,\"3\":-0.026795387,\"4\":-0.03757,\"5\":-0.02809906,\"6\":-0.016090393,\"7\":-0.040496826,\"8\":-0.05318451,\"9\":-0.0254566,\"10\":-0.054562772}},\"NUMBER_TAG\":\"2145600\",\"error\":{}}","CerId":null,"Id":null,"Asse":null,"Id":1,"id":"074222a38-2816-42c7-b95c-6644448ba9d","t":-2}
```

Row 1 is:

```
{"Name":"","Seri":21000000,"SiName":"","As":"","PId":21070101,"ICheck":0,"SeeNum":405097041391424,"Type":0,"Counter":33,"PaId":0,"MeType":30,"RecTime":"2021-10-21T09:04:41.0151Z","ReaTime":null,"Cape":"2021-10-21T09:04:40.644","Status":0,"text":"{\"TYPE_TAG\":\"00\",\"ENSORAG\":{\"date_time\":\"2021-10-21 09:04:40.644\",\"seber\":10,\"seqmber\":405097041391424,\"lo_name\":\"\",\"accati\":{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":-0.037665367,\"2\":-0.033863068,\"3\":-0.026795387,\"4\":-0.03757,\"5\":-0.02809906,\"6\":-0.016090393,\"7\":-0.040496826,\"8\":-0.05318451,\"9\":-0.025012016,\"10\":-0.057872772}},\"ATTACHED_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER_TAG\":\"21000000\",\"error\":{}}","CerId":null,"Id":null,"Asse":null,"Id":0,"id":"075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d","t":-1}
```

Row 2 is:

```
{"Name":"","Seri":4560000,"SiName":"","As":"","PId":2107401,"ICheck":0,"SeeNum":40509704561424,"Type":0,"Counter":34,"PaId":0,"MeType":31,"RecTime":"2021-10-21T09:04:41.0151Z","ReaTime":null,"Cape":"2021-10-21T09:04:40.644","Status":0,"text":"{\"TYPE_TAG\":\"00\",\"ENSORAG\":{\"date_time\":\"2021-10-21 09:04:40.644\",\"seber\":10,\"seqmber\":405097041391424,\"lo_name\":\"\",\"accati\":{\"0\":0.0,\"1\":-0.037665367,\"2\":-0.033863068,\"3\":-0.026795387,\"4\":-0.03757,\"5\":-0.02809906,\"6\":-0.016090393,\"7\":-0.040496826,\"8\":-0.05318451,\"9\":-0.025012016,\"10\":-0.057872772}},\"ATTTAG\":\"21000000\",\"error\":{}}","CerId":null,"Id":null,"Asse":null,"Id":0,"id":"075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d","t":-2}
```

The structure of a row is like the below image:

[image]

In my opinion, First I should split each row and then create a data frame and insert each value in the related column. After that, I append to a blob.  Is it right?

How can I do? What is your suggested solution?

**Edited:**
My code for reading from service bus:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

connection_str = "**"
topic_name = "***"
subscription_name = "***"

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=connection_str, logging_enable=True)

with servicebus_client:
    # get the Subscription Receiver object for the subscription
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(
        topic_name=topic_name, subscription_name=subscription_name, )
    with receiver:
        for msg in receiver:
            print("Received: " + str(msg))
            # complete the message so that the message is removed from the subscription
            receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

Comment: Hi, Just need some more clarity. Is the concatenation of all the 50 JSONs sent as 1 message into service bus? Or are they sent as separate messages but you are receiving it as 1 message in your function? Can you cut paste the code from your function that would help us understand? I'm assuming you are using the Service bus python SDK and if the JSONs are being sent as separate messages there should be no problem receiving them as separate messages. If there are being sent as a single message, is it feasible to change how the messages are sent to Service bus? Do we have access to that code too?

Comment: Hi, There is a system then, sends 1 separate message every second to Service Bus. Each message is like `Row1`. I don't have access to the sender system. I need to archive this data. My suggestion use Azure Function with a time trigger, for example, every 5 minutes connect to Service Bus and read all messages (etc, 50 or 100 received messages as 1 message). Let me if you have other questions.

Comment: Please share the code how you are receiving the messages in your function.

Comment: @Anupam Chand - I added my question body in the edited section. This is a sample code from the Microsoft website ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues) ).   Instead of print msg, I want to separate msg and append to a blob.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Hi @Shadi, have you checked my answer below? If it answers your questions, kindly mark it as the answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the messages are sent individually, you can process them individually. There is no need to concatenate into a string. Just keep appending them into a data frame. Below sample is for a queue but you can extend to a topic/subscription. I've also attached the results to show you what the output looks like.

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

CONNECTION_STR = 'Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
QUEUE_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)

with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    
    # create an Empty DataFrame object
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    msg_concat = ""
    dfs = []
    with receiver:
        received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            msg_dict = json.loads(str(msg))
            df2 = json_normalize(msg_dict)
            df = df.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
            receiver.complete_message(msg)
print(df)
print("Receive is done.")


  Name      Seri SiName As  ...  Id  Asse                                    id  t
0       21000000            ...   0  None  075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d -1
1        4560000            ...   0  None  075f0a38-2816-42c7-b95c-66c425b8ba9d -2

[2 rows x 21 columns]
Receive is done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider sample data with three rows:

```
data = '{"Name": "Hassan", "code":"12"}{"Name": "Jack", "code":"345"}{"Name": "Jack", "code":"345"}'
```

Here is how you can get dataframe from this data:

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = [literal_eval(d + '}')for d in data.split('}')[0:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

`Output:`

```
     Name code
0  Hassan   12
1    Jack  345
2    Jack  345
```

Comment: For clarifying I edited my question. First, I need to split each row and then find a solution to archive in Azure Storage.

Comment: What do you mean by `splitting a row`? I mean you have a json data you can load it directly into a dataframe, why do you need splitting of row?

Comment: When I read from Azure Service Bus, it's not a JSON. It's a string message, that contains for example 50 rows. The structure of each row is JSON. For your information, when I received the message, 50 rows concated together. Please see row 1 and row 2 in my question.

Comment: And how are the rows separated in original string? I mean what's the delimeter or how did you split the original string in row_1, row_2 etc?

Comment: Each row starts with `{"Name"`. Is it possible to separate with this condition? Or it's not good.

Comment: Check the edited answer. Will it work for your case?

Comment: It will not. There is no delimiter between the messages in the question.  You can use the example provided in the question and check it against your code.

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: Have you tried the code with the sample provided in the question?